# What is the use of decltype in this code ?

Tags: c++, c++11, compilation, compiler-errors, decltype

I have a written a small piece of code which throws a lot of error, If I dont't use the `decltype` keyword while with the `decltype` keyword it compiles fine : -

```
   std::function<bool(int,int)> f2 = [dist](int n1,int n2) {if(dist[n1] < dist[n2]) return false ; return true ; } ; 
        priority_queue<int,vector<int>,decltype(f2)>  pq(f2)  ;
```

Here, I wanted to declare a `priority_queue` with my own custom comparison function, so I decided to use `std::function` and lambdas.
Also, `dist` is a `std::vector<int>`

But strangely , the code gives error if I replace `decltype(f2)` with just `f2`.

Why is is so ?

Comment: For the record, that is *not* a valid comparator for a `priority_queue`. It isn't a strict weak ordering.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Referring to [documentations](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/queue/priority_queue/), `priority_queue` must receive 3 types. Here, types `int` and `vector<int>` are followed by the type of f2 and not f2. `decltype` gives you a type not a variable.

Note that: `decltype` = `typeof` but in official way

Answer (score 3):

Third parameter of `priority_queue` template class is type of predicate. Here `decltype(f2)` actually gives a type of `f2`, instead `decltype` you can just write `std::function<bool(int,int)>`.

Comment: But shouldn't we give only f2 instead of `std::function<bool(int,int)>` .

Comment: @ps06756 no, f2 is object of this type.

Comment: f2 is an object. You can't use an object for a template parameter that expects a type. An object is not a type. A type is not an object.

Answer (score -1):

I don't know why you use this `std::function<bool(int,int)>` as your return type for your lambda function, I would use simply `auto` instead since std::function may also offer some overhead during type construction. Let the compiler make its best choice for you if you don't know what it does.